# GNOME does not start at starup after upgrading Ubuntu from 22.04 to 23.04

Tags: upgrade, 22.04, gnome-shell, ubuntu-gnome, 23.04

I updated Ubuntu from 22.04 to 23.04 following [this](https://jumpcloud.com/blog/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu-22-04-to-ubuntu-23-04) guide. After I rebooted GNOME did not started and dropped me in the tty. I tried `sudo startx gnome-shell` and worked. My customizations on desktop are there too. But I can not make GNOME to launch at system startup. What should I do?

Comment: I'll suggest in future you use *official* guides, as the procedure you followed better fits Debian upgrade rather than Ubuntu. When Ubuntu 22.10 reached EOL the official *release-upgrade* method would have upgraded a 22.04 system to 23.04 which was CI & QA tested, instead of your 3rd party suggested approach (*which was intended for use before the official path opened up*)  *Posted here as you appeared & quickly disappeared on IRC*

Comment: Yes I will definelitly not gonna use a third party guide again.